# Generate empty json object using moshi json library

Tags: android, moshi

What should my data class be so that when I convert it to json using moshi it would come out like this?

```
{"id":"abcdef""formValues":{}}
```

At the moment my class looks like this.

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
class MyDataClass(
    @Json(name = "id")
    val id: String
) {

    @Json(name = "formValues")
    val formValues = FormValues()

    @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
    class FormValues
}
```

But you see the statement

```
Moshi.Builder().build().adapter(MyDataClass::class.java).toJson(MyDataClass("abcdef"))
```

produces this

```
{"id": "abcdef"}
```

and I want this

```
{"id":"abcdef""formValues":{}}
```

Answer (score 2):

It turns out you have to use `var` instead of `val` for your class members. I change my class to this

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
class MyDataClass(
    @Json(name = "id")
    var id: String
) {

    @Json(name = "formValues")
    var formValues = FormValues()

    @JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
    class FormValues
}
```

and moshi generates json like this

```
{"id":"abcdef""formValues":{}}
```